# Model process for curved objects (Stool Legs)

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to wrap my head around this for a while now. It's a simple question for what I think will be a not so simple answer. How would you go about modeling one leg of this stool? I would like to do it without using sculpt mode because I can't get things quite clean enough.[image]

Comment: Kinda subjective and vague. Personally I'd just dive in with a cube and extruding, making sure to use proportional editing and a subsurf to get nice smooth curve. The only real complex thing may be the topology of the spiral but you'd just figure it out as you went. I think ultimately it comes down just to diving in and trying. You could make it straight and then use a lattice to deform it but ultimately its not too complex a shape. What do you think you would struggle with if you tried to model it?

Answer (score 3):

You could begin with the top spiral, making sure that your edges follow the slots, so that it's easy to extrude or add edge loops:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's for the wildcat test ?
Maybe you should train more before applying to this job, but here's the way i did it: I first took the ref picture and reoriented it because the leg is 45° and not perpendicular to the camera, here's a tut how to do it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj006df-boI

Then you just follow the shape (you can go full quad its possible for this shape) :)
Good luck dude

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a curve or the skin modifier as a base and then edit the mesh from there. If you're using the curve spline, you can convert the curve to a mesh after you're satisfied with the shape.